# python version of synthpop

Tags: machine-learning, simulation, synthpop

I find a interesting package to generate synthetic data with dataset:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/synthpop/synthpop.pdf
It is using cart approach to generate synthetic data
but it is a R package, is there any similar package for Python?

Comment: It might by the same name, synthpop, but unfortunately the python version referred to is not a python version of the R-based original.

Answer (score 1):

I could only find documentation supporting the R implementation. However, the Python installation `pip install synthpop` does work. There is some more information at https://github.com/udst/synthpop. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a Python package, **PySynth**, aimed at data synthesis that should do what you need: https://pypi.org/project/pysynth/ The IPF method used there now does not work well for datasets with many columns, but it should be sufficient for most needs. The Python synthpop package is not an analog of the R version, it aims at generating synthetic population, which is a related but different task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent package available at https://github.com/hazy/synthpop.

> **synthpop**
>
> Python implementation of the [R package synthpop](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/synthpop/index.html).
>
> The R implementation of synthpop is a tool for producing synthetic versions of microdata containing confidential information so that they are safe to be released to users for exploratory analysis.